# An equation which gives me 10 = 0 but 100 = 100

Tags: math, mathematical-optimization

In one line, **how to get an equation which will give me 0 if I pass 10, but 100 if I pass 100?**

So that, for the following numbers, the value will be something like:

10 -> 0

100 -> 100

Of course my number can be anything between 10 to 100.

Comment: Linear or exponential interpolation?

Comment: can you elaborate your question please?

Comment: I don't see how this is related to programming at all. It's a mathematical equation if anything.  Are you sure about the 50? otherwise it's just f(x) = x + (x-100)/9

Comment: If the 50 is there, you could simply find the quadratic polynomial that passes those 3 points, assuming one exists.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Comment: @Pang : I agree. I even tried to delete the question, but it's not letting me delete and asking to flag it instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got my answer, the equation is something like this:

X = (Y*10-100)/9

Now try putting any value between 10 to 100 in it.

Answer (score 1):

```
int input = ...;
int result = (input <= 10 ? 0 : 100 * (input - 10) / 90);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
if (i == 0) return 10;
if (i == 100) return 100;
```

Anything else is left to your imagination.

```
return i * 9 / 10 + 10;
```

or

```
return (i * i + 1110) / 111;
```